# Application to graphically design a graph database schema?

Tags: database-design, orientdb, graph-databases

I am creating a graph database in OrientDB and I would like to share the schema design with other members of my team. For that, I would like to use some application to draw the node types, edges types, and their attributes, so we can all visualize and discuss the design. I am currently using Lucidchart. What do you use? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Hi these types of questions (i.e. recommend software or a book) are often not welcome on SO unless you have done more research so just be aware of this in the future. That being said you can try [http://linkurio.us/](http://linkurio.us/) for graph visualization. I am just not sure if they interface with OrientDB directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/) for this purpose. It's ontology developing tool. May be it will suit you.